# Ungroup pandas dataframe column values separated by comma

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I Have pandas dataframe which is grouped wanted to ungroup the dataframe the column values are separated comma the dataframe which is looking as below

```
 col1             col2   name  exams 

0,0,0                0,0,0,   A1   exm1,exm2, exm3
0,1,0,20           0,0,2,20   A2   exm1,exm2, exm4, exm5
0,0,0,30           0,0,20,20  A3   exm1,exm2, exm3, exm5
```

output how I wanted

```
   col1   col2  name exam
    0       0    A1   exm1
    0       0    A1   exm2
    0       0    A1   exm3
    0       0    A2   exm1
    1       0    A2   exm2
    0       2    A2   exm4
    20      20   A2   exm5
     ..............
    30      20   A3   exm5
```

I am tried with [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)
 but not able get proper approach any one please give me suggestion how can I get my output

Comment: Multiple column explode after split ....

Comment: @BEN_YO I tried its showing nameError: name 'explode' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Try with explode, notice , explode is the new function after pandas 0.25.0

```
df[['col1','col2','exams']]=df[['col1','col2','exams']].apply(lambda x : x.str.split(','))
df = df.join(pd.concat([df.pop(x).explode() for x in ['col1','col2','exams']],axis=1))
Out[62]: 
  name col1 col2 exams
0   A1    0    0  exm1
0   A1    0    0  exm2
0   A1    0    0  exm3
1   A2    0    0  exm1
1   A2    1    0  exm2
1   A2    0    2  exm4
1   A2   20   20  exm5
2   A3    0    0  exm1
2   A3    0    0  exm2
2   A3    0   20  exm3
2   A3   30   20  exm5
```